# Consulta Python POO funcion catalogar()

Tags: python, poo

La parte que me falta completar es esta que es justo el final del ejercicio...

Modifica la función catalogar() para que reciba un argumento optativo ruedas, haciendo que muestre únicamente los que su número de ruedas concuerde con el valor del argumento. También debe mostrar un mensaje "Se han encontrado {} vehículos con {} ruedas:" únicamente si se envía el argumento ruedas. Ponla a prueba con 0, 2 y 4 ruedas como valor.

os adjunto el codigo que tengo hasta el momento, para ver si podeis ayudarme a encontrar como solucionar el final

```
class Vehiculo():
    
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas

    def __str__(self):
        return "Color {}, {} ruedas".format(self.color, self.ruedas)

class Coche(Vehiculo):

    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada, lista_Vehiculos=[]):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
        self.lista_Vehiculos = lista_Vehiculos

    def __str__(self):
        return "Color {}, {} Ruedas, {} Velocidad, {} CC".format(self.color, self.ruedas, self.velocidad, self.cilindrada )

class Camioneta(Coche):
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada,carga):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
        self.carga = carga
        
    def __str__(self):
        return"Color {}, {} Ruedas, {} Velocidad, {} CC,{} KG".format( self.color, self.ruedas, self.velocidad, self.cilindrada, self.carga )

class Bicicleta(Vehiculo):
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,tipo):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        self.tipo = tipo
        
    def __str__(self):
        return"Color {},{} Ruedas, Tipo {}".format(self.color, self.ruedas, self.tipo)

class Motocicleta(Bicicleta):
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,tipo,velocidad,cilindrada):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
        
    def __str__(self):
        return"Color {},{} Ruedas, Tipo {}, {} Km/h, {} CC".format(self.color, self.ruedas, self.tipo, self.velocidad, self.cilindrada)
        
vehiculo1 = Vehiculo("rojo",2)
coche1 = Coche("verde", 4, 120, 2000)
coche2 = Coche("azul",4,300,4000)
coche3 = Coche("blanco",4,60,800)
print(vehiculo1)
print(coche1)
print(coche2)
print(coche3)
camioneta1 = Camioneta("blanco",4,100,2000,3000)
print(camioneta1)
bici1 = Bicicleta("amarillo", 2,"MountanBike")
print(bici1)
moto1 = Motocicleta("rojo",2,"Trial",90,300)
print(moto1)

lista_Vehiculos=[type(coche1).__name__,type(coche2).__name__, type(camioneta1).__name__, type(bici1).__name__,type(moto1).__name__]

def catalogar():
    for p in lista_Vehiculos:
            print(p)
            
catalogar()


def catalogar1(lista_Vehiculos, ruedas=None):
    if ruedas is not None:
        vehiculos_encontrados = 0
        for vehiculo in lista_Vehiculos:
            if Vehiculo.ruedas == ruedas:
                vehiculos_encontrados += 1
        print("Se han encontrado {} vehículos con {} ruedas:".format(vehiculos_encontrados, ruedas))
        for vehiculo in lista_Vehiculos:
            if vehiculo.ruedas == ruedas:
                print(vehiculo)
    else:
        for vehiculo in lista_Vehiculos:
            print(vehiculo)

catalogar1(lista_Vehiculos, ruedas = 2)
```

Comment: En este sitio no guiamos ni completamos códigos. Si buscas ayuda para terminar el ejercicio, te recomiendo recurrir a otra pagina o a nuestro chat cuando tengas suficiente reputación. Esto es así ya que el sitio tiene formato de preguntas y respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error es la lista de vehiculos, que debe contener objetos **vehiculos**, no sus nombres.

```
lista_Vehiculos = [coche1, coche2, camioneta1, bici1, moto1]
```

La función catalogar recorre la lista de vehiculos consultando el número de ruedas y agregandolos a una lista si tiene la cantidad requerida:

```
def catalogar(lista, ruedas=4):
    salida = []
    for x in lista:
        if x.ruedas == ruedas:
            salida.append(x)
    print(f"Se han encontrado {len(salida)} vehículos con {ruedas} ruedas:")
    return salida
```

produce

```
Se han encontrado 0 vehículos con 0 ruedas:
Se han encontrado 2 vehículos con 2 ruedas:
Se han encontrado 3 vehículos con 4 ruedas:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!